# Change only a single method of a class from java to kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I know how to convert java class to kotlin class in android studio. I am currently learning rxJava and kotlin simultaneously,more so trying to use rx in kotlin. I am facing issues while defining and declaring variables and methods in kotlin. Hence I would like to use the same method in java class or activity and see how it works in kotlin,if I can first write it in java and change to kotlin. So is it possible to convert only a single method in java activity to kotlin in Android studio or anywhere else ?

Comment: you can only have kotlin code in a kotlin file, same with java. create another kotlin file in your project. and paste any java method in that kotlin file. It will be converted to Kotlin  :)

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot it worked :) I kind of accidentally did it just a while ago :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **IDE** (IntelliJ, AndroidStudio) can help you with converting *Kotlin -> Java*. Just create a simple `.kt` file and paste your Java method there. You'll be asked whether you'd like to have it converted into Kotlin.

*BTW:* If you're having trouble with the Kotlin *syntax*, maybe it'd be better to ask a specific question so one can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you it did work that way :) Yes I will ask specific query as well, thank you :)

Comment: Great, have fun!